# How to delete a shortcut in cmd or powershell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I want to delete file shortcuts using `cmd` or `powershell` but I just can't. Whenever I type `dir` into `cmd` or `powershell` they don't show `.lnk` files nor scripts languages can show them(as much as I have browsed the net). There plenty questions about this but not only they are very old but also most of them are for directory shortcuts whereas I need for file shortcuts. I just can't find a reliable solution to this.

Comment: What lnk files from what location? Your Desktop? Keep in mind they're spread across multiple locations and there are some new options for shortcuts that are not based on lnk files.

Comment: for me, this >>> `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" -Filter '*.lnk' -File` <<< gives all the `*.lnk` files in my desktop dir.

Comment: @Seth yep from my desktop and for the sake of testing im using a windows 7

Comment: @Lee_Dailey apparently `powershell` threw an Error `Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.`  but after removing `-file` it worked but no result showed

Comment: try running `attrib` in a cmd window on the desktop. If you see it then, then the shortcut has special attributes set. Do note that it is also possible the shortcut on the desktop is actually not on YOUR desktop, but on the common desktop. You can test this by opening an explorer window and go to `shell:publicdesktop`. If you see the shortcut there too, then its location is C:\Users\Public\Desktop

Comment: @thecowmilk - ah! you are running an older version of PoSh. i have 5.1 ... but i think w7 comes with 2 or 3. there are upgrades available for win7 to get to ps5.1 ... you may want to look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the shortcuts are placed on the "All users" desktop rather than your own desktop.

By default, on your desktop, you see icons placed on both your desktop and the All Users desktop.

If you type `attrib` on your own desktop folder in cmd, you can see all files with their attributes. This includes showing hidden files. It will then also show you what attributes are set, such as hidden. If this is the case `dir /ah` will show them too.

[image]

However, if attrib does not show them, then the links are placed in the All users desktop space instead. You can test this by opening an explorer window and typing in the address: `shell:common desktop`

Explorer will jump to `C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop` and if the shortcuts are there, they will now show up. You can do a `dir` in this folder from command prompt too.
[image]

Comment: Thanks dude they were really in public desktop but I have a problem that `mklink` opened as admin in `cmd` doesn't make working shortcuts by using the following command `mklink shortcutname C:\path\to\exe` any idea? Thanks.

Comment: mklink is not the tool to create shortcuts because it creates softlinks or hardlinks, not .lnk files. Powershell can create shortcuts though.

Comment: the it seems most of documented sites are outdated? how can I do it using powershell?

Comment: either way I found a way to make it with vbs. thanks.

Comment: `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "C:\temp" -Name "calc.lnk" -Value "c:\windows\system32\calc.exe"`

Comment: well this didnt worked but maybe im in windows 7 with the old base powershell

Comment: Ah, the new-item with -itemtype symboliclink is a feature of PowerShell 5. You need to update to a newer version of Powershell